# In mongodb, drop collections, but still in db.stats() ? In db.stats(), fileSize is greater, greater than storageSize

Tags: mongodb

I used `db.coll.drop()` to drop two collections in my MongoDB database. There are only system.indexes in my database now. But the output of `db.stats()` is:

```
mongos> db.stats()
{
"raw" : {
    "rs0/sever01:27017,server02:27017,server03:27020" : {
        "db" : "mydb",
        "collections" : 2,
        "objects" : 1,
        "avgObjSize" : 48,
        "dataSize" : 48,
        "storageSize" : 49152,
        "numExtents" : 3,
        "indexes" : 0,
        "indexSize" : 0,
        "fileSize" : 4226809856,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
        },
        "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 128,
            "totalSize" : 2680152064
        },
        "ok" : 1
    }
},
"objects" : 1,
"avgObjSize" : 48,
"dataSize" : 48,
"storageSize" : 49152,
"numExtents" : 3,
"indexes" : 0,
"indexSize" : 0,
"fileSize" : 4226809856,
"extentFreeList" : {
    "num" : 128,
    "totalSize" : 2680152064
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Why is the collections number still 2? Why is fileSize is so large?

And when I run `show dbs`, the output shows that my database is about 4 GB.

I am not sure whether my issue is the same as the issue of dropping database here [Removing Database from sharded cluster in Mongo DB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65021/removing-database-from-sharded-cluster-in-mongo-db).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Number of collection is equal 2:  The 2 collections are the system.indexes system.users. Execute the "show collections" command under your database to confirm.
- Filesize: MongoDB allocates "physical files" or files on disk per database. For example eventsdb.0, eventsdb.1 ... Collections are stored with a distributed way within these files. Dropping a database will delete all these files and return the disk space to the OS. Dropping a collection marks the pages within the files as dead but doesn't reduce the filesize. You might have heard that as fragmentation. To reclaim disk space you need to execute the repairDatabase (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/#dbcmd.repairDatabase) which i don't recommend because uses the global lock. Instead if you running on a 3 member replica set which is recommended, just stop one SECONDARY, delete the data directory and start the SECONDARY again. The initial sync will remove fragmentation.
- Show dbs: Show dbs warps the size from filesize, so the number you see is correct.

Comment: (1)There is only **system.indexes**. (2) In order to drop the collection **eventsdb**, I need to delete the **eventsdb.0** , the **eventsdb.1**, the **eventsdb.2** and the **eventsdb.ns** in the **data directory**? (3) Thanks, I will have a look at **fragmentation**...

Comment: (1)There is only **system.indexes**. (2) In order to drop the database **mydb**, I need to delete the **mydb.0** , the **mydb.1**, the **mydb.2** and the **mydb.ns** in the **data directory**? I just need to drop one collection. **Where is the data directory for the specific collection? There are only data directory for database.**(3) Thanks, I will have a look at **fragmentation**...

Comment: (1) Please share a fresh db.stats() and show collections from mongos (2) No, you need to execute use mydb; db.dropdatabase()

Comment: I just need to drop the collections, not the database.

Comment: You have already dropped the collections, this is what i read on your original post. If you mean free the space then use repairDatabase or initialSync.

Comment: Thanks. right. Which data directory should I delete? I just have one data directory, which includes these files: **admin.0  admin.ns  mydb.0  mydb.1  mydb.2  mydb.ns  journal  local.0  local.1  local.2  local.ns  mongod.lock  test.0  test.ns  _tmp**.

Comment: There is always one data directory. If your data dir is /dbdata/data Run something like rm -rf /dbdata/data/* , delete all contents of data directory. Stop mongo first.